# React does not recognize the prop on a DOM element, how to fix it?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, react-props

I am learning React and I'm stuck on this warning : "react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: React does not recognize the `isSelected` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `isselected` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element."

The warning appears when I render my Survey component, but not each time. Sometimes I need to reload the page a few times before it appears.

I have a Survey with 2 clickables buttons : "yes" and "no" to answers questions. I want the selected answer to have a box-shadow CSS property on it so I made a conditional in my CSS, I use CSS-in-JS.
It is working as expected but I have the warning...

Here is the code of my Survey element :

```
// various imports

const SurveyContainer = styled.div`...
`;

const QuestionTitle = styled.h2`...
`;

const QuestionContent = styled.span`...
`;

const LinkWrapper = styled.div`...
`;

const ReplyBox = styled.button`
    // other CSS properties
    box-shadow: ${(props) =>
        props.isSelected ? `0px 0px 0px 2px ${colors.primary} inset` : "none"};
    &:first-child {
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    &:last-of-type {
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
`;

const ReplyWrapper = styled.div`
    // CSS properties
`;

function Survey() {
    const { questionNumber } = useParams();
    const questionNumberInt = parseInt(questionNumber);
    const prevQuestionNumber =
        questionNumberInt === 1 ? 1 : questionNumberInt - 1;
    const nextQuestionNumber = questionNumberInt + 1;
    const [surveyData, setSurveyData] = useState({});
    const [isDataLoading, setDataLoading] = useState(false);
    const { answers, saveAnswers } = useContext(SurveyContext);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    function saveReply(answer) {
        saveAnswers({ [questionNumber]: answer });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchSurvey() {...
        }
        fetchSurvey();
    }, []);

    if (error) {...
    }

    return (
        <SurveyContainer>
            <QuestionTitle>Question {questionNumber}</QuestionTitle>
            {isDataLoading ? (
                <Loader />
            ) : (
                <QuestionContent>{surveyData[questionNumber]}</QuestionContent>
            )}
            <ReplyWrapper>
                <ReplyBox
                    onClick={() => saveReply(true)}
                    isSelected={answers[questionNumber] === true}
                >
                    Oui
                </ReplyBox>
                <ReplyBox
                    onClick={() => saveReply(false)}
                    isSelected={answers[questionNumber] === false}
                >
                    Non
                </ReplyBox>
            </ReplyWrapper>
            <LinkWrapper>
                <Link to={`/survey/${prevQuestionNumber}`}>Précédent</Link>
                {surveyData[questionNumberInt + 1] ? (
                    <Link to={`/survey/${nextQuestionNumber}`}>Suivant</Link>
                ) : (
                    <Link to="/results">Résultats</Link>
                )}
            </LinkWrapper>
        </SurveyContainer>
    );
}

export default Survey;
```

How can I do to still use the prop to get my condition validation for the CSS code without ending-up with this error ?

Maybe I can't write "isSelected={answers[questionNumber] === true}" in the "ReplyBox" because it is a button styled-component and not an other React component ? But I still have to use a button...

Is there anything else than a prop that I could use to get the same result?

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue with the code posted that would cause this message. It would be good to track down, but also understand that this is not an error - just a warning. It shouldn't break your code and also shouldn't show up in a prod build. It's just trying to help you out by warning you that you're passing a prop that won't have any affect

Answer (score 1):

In your "CSS properties" of "ReplyBox", do "props.$isSelected" and add the $ in your "isSelected" in your return